# is it possible to obtain layerInfo from the Layer's URL

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, layers

I am trying to fetch the names of the layers in the MapService, so that I can populate them in the dijit.form.select. I am able to get the `layerInfo` when the ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer is added to the map by using,

```
map.getLayer(map.layerIds[0]).layerInfos[0].name
```

But this is only after the layer has been added to the map. Is there some way by which I can get the layerInfo names directly from the URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, send a request to the layer's URL to retrieve info as JSON and then pull out what you need. The [Request Layer Info sample](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jssamples/data_requestLayerInfo.html) shows how to do this.

**Edit**:  Here's a link to a tweaked version of the sample that shows querying a service for layer names:  http://jsfiddle.net/Cuef5/ Note that the URL being used is for a map service:

```
http://sampleserver5.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Energy/Geology/MapServer
```

As opposed to using a URL for a single layer like:

```
http://sampleserver5.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Energy/Geology/MapServer/3
```

Comment: thanks for the reply @Derek but this gives all the details of the attributes in the layer. I simply want the layer name, which we get from `map.getLayer(map.layerIds[0]).layerInfos[0].name`

Comment: @Sam007 there's no way to request only the names of the layers in a map service– you have to get all map service info, then navigate the returned object to access layer names. This is a quick, relatively cheap operation since it's a single request for not much data.

Comment: The reason I need it is I am having a `dijit.form.select` where I am adding the map service names in the items and on selection of a map service, another `dijit.select` will be populated with the names of the layers in the selected map service. So I have the URL but not sure how to obtain only the layer names to populate them in the dropdown. This is my application, http://msgist2011.grd.arizona.edu/project/tp_dock.html, if u click on the Mapping the Data docked floating pane and then change selection u can see the layer list but I am not able to populate it with the appropriate name

Comment: I am getting the returned object but not sure how to navigate to the layer names? The link, http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/samples/data_requestLayerInfo/index.html, gives the info of the layer's attribute table not the name

Comment: @Sam007 you'll need to query the map service endpoint instead of the endpoint for a particular layer. I've edited my answer with a link to a jsfiddle showing how to do this.

Comment: YESssssssssss this is exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot @Derek

Comment: @Sam007 happy to help!

Comment: Sorry to bother you @Derek but can u also take a look at this question. been stuck on it for quite some time now. http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/39275/getresultimagelayer-is-not-working