# Info from the getResultImageLayer missing

Tags: geoprocessing, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-server

I was finally able to get the [result layer overlaid on my application](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/39275/getresultimagelayer-is-not-working) but now I am facing another problem.

The output of the layer url does not show any field or attribute details. I am not sure why this is happening? The output looks like this,

[image]

As you can see that it is only describing the Extent and other Map properties but the attribute details, which are visible in the jobs folder of the newly created final_shp, is missing on the url and so I am not able to fetch anything onto the map.

Any Idea how I can resolve this?